Electromagnetic Field in a 3D Cavity with Lossy Boundary
I would like to find the electric and magnetic fields inside a cubic cavity with a lossy boundary (i.e. NOT a perfect conductor). I  assume that the interior of the cavity is filled with a homogeneous medium with permittivity $\varepsilon$ and permeability $\mu$ and that the cavity is situated between $-L/2 \leq x \leq L/2$, $-L/2 \leq y \leq L/2$, $-L/2 \leq z \leq L/2$. To find the electric field, I would like to solve the inhomogeneous wave equation
$$ (\nabla^2 + k^2)\vec{E}(\omega,x,y,z) = -\mathrm{i}\omega\mu ~\vec{J}(\omega,x,y,z)$$
where $\vec{J}$ is a given current density and $|k| = \omega /c$ (and similarly I would solve the inhomogeneous wave equation for the magnetic field). If this were a lossless cavity, we would require the tangential component of the electric field to vanish at the boundary of the prism. As far as I know, there is a somewhat straightforward procedure to find the Green's function for this wave equation with lossless boundary conditions (as long as you're not worried about having an expression that also holds in the source region; that is the case for me). But what boundary conditions should I use to account for losses? Can I simply use separation of variables and apply the Robin boundary condition in each dimension? I saw in Strauss' book Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction that the Robin boundary condition can be used to model a string that loses energy at the endpoints if we take $a_0, a_L$ positive in
$$Y' - a_0 Y = 0 \quad \text{at}\;x=0 \\ Y' + a_L Y = 0 \quad \text{at}\;x=L$$
where $Y(x)$ is the string's displacement from equilibrium and obeys the homogeneous wave equation $Y'' = -\lambda Y $ (the primes denote differentiation with respect to $x$). The idea is to solve for the eigenfunctions in this homogeneous case and then expand every solution in the inhomogeneous case in terms of these eigenfunctions. However, I have not seen anyone do this Robin boundary condition business to get closed form solutions for the electric field in a lossy 3D cavity so there must be something about this that doesn't check out. I've seen that a good approximation for small boundary losses is to add a small positive imaginary component to $k$. Is that the only way?

Welcome to Physics SE! You can find an alternative method in Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, section 8.7: "Power Losses in a Cavity; Q of a Cavity."

The derivation in Jackson (and in section 12.4.5 of my textbook) assumes the power loss is very small per cycle so that the lossless electric and magnetic fields can be used.  I treat the one-dimensional case in section 11 of my book, but I think it would be a PhD thesis to do it for the 3-D case.
